# How to replace percentage value to replace with some string value in percentage specific 2d horizontal fusion charts

Tags: fusioncharts

I have a 2D horizontal stack chart and it is based on percentage so in each stack it is showing percentage but my requirement is to show some string in place of percentage.
I have seen in fusion chart documents and it is mentioned to use displayValue attribute to provide some other value to display but it doesn't work as I am specifying tool-text. Below URL is giving this information.
http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?guide-for-web-developers/php/PHP_BasicExample.html
But I don't know how to specify tool-text.
Please help!!!

Comment: You need to provide more details than that. You using FusionCharts v3.x or FusionCharts Free? What data XML/JSON are you providing? What changes you did to achieve what you want and it still did not work? Also, do you want tool-tip or the displayValue to change 9its not that clear)?

Answer (score 0):

give numbersuffix='%25' to display '%' as suffix

sample : http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/docs/Contents/Adv_SpChar_Percent.html

Answer (score 0):

To Configure Text Labels instead of Numeric Data Values, Specify the text you want to display using the **displayValue** attribute under data within the particular data plot.

Refer to the code below:

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var salesChart = new FusionCharts({
      type: 'column2d',
      renderAt: 'chart-container',
      id: 'myChart',
      width: '450',
      height: '300',
      dataFormat: 'json',
      dataSource: {
        "chart": {
          "theme": "fusion",
          "caption": "Quarterly Revenue",
          "subcaption": "Last year",
          "xAxisName": "Quarter",
          "yAxisName": "Amount (In USD)",
          "showValues": "1",
          "numberPrefix": "$"
        },
        "data": [{
          "label": "Q1",
          "value": "1950000"
        }, {
          "label": "Q2",
          "value": "1450000"
        }, {
          "label": "Q3",
          "value": "1730000"
        }, {
          "label": "Q4",
          "value": "2120000",
          //Custom display string
          "displayValue": "Year's best"
        }]
      }
    })
    .render();
});
```

Column2d example [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhz5ey76/)

stackedcolumn2d example [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1e8tpsyv/)